# jQuery: how to open link within SVG's with fancybox?

Tags: jquery, svg, hyperlink, fancybox

I have a link around every SVG element, and when I click on a link I want an image to pop up with the help of fancybox. So far the image just pops up in a new site, and not through fancybox. It worked out just fine before I added the SVG elements. Any tips?

I have tried something like this:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="RAM" xlink:href="http://www.studioinfotronic.it/images/Memory-Module-icon.png" target="_blank"><polygon points="142.961,71.376 117.479,174.914 117.479,186.584 268.354,186.618 278.195,83.04 278.195,71.376"/></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4AFaR/3/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that fancybox has issues getting the content from svg's links (`xlink:href`).

As a workaround, I would build the gallery manually using the `.each()` method like :

```
var gallery = [];
$(".fancybox").each(function (i) {
    gallery[i] = {
        href: $(this).attr("xlink:href"),
        title: $(this).attr("title")
    };
    $(this).on("click", function () {
        $.fancybox(gallery, {
            index: i,
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'inside',
                    position: 'top',
                }
            },
            openSpeed: 'slow',
            closeSpeed: 'slow',
            autoDimensions: true
        });
        return false;
    }); // on
}); // each
```

See forked <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E3jX6/)</kbd>